# For what integer $e$ is a group $G$ necessarily Abelian?

Tags: group-theory

If $e$ is the smallest positive integer such that $x^e=1$ for every $x$ in group $G$, and if $e=2$, then it is easy to proof that $G$ is Abelian.

$\forall x,y\in G$, $x^2=y^2=(xy)^2=1 \rightarrow x^{-1}=x$, $y^{-1}=y$ and $(xy)^{-1}=xy$,

so $xy=(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx$.

My question is, for what other integer $e$ is a group $G$ necessarily Abelian?

If the integer $p\ge2$ such that $x^p=1$ for every $x$ in group $G$, by some similar steps, I can proof $(xy)^{p-1}=y^{p-1}x^{p-1}$. But I can not know for what integer p the G is also Abelian.

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32116/exponent-of-a-group) is a discussion on MO of a group of exponent $3$ that is non-abelian. So at a minimum, primality of $e$ is not sufficient.

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_two_implies_abelian